# Do you need seperate visa for your children if they are registered in your passport

Tags: visas, passports, children, eu-citizens

I share my passport with my daughters. It means that they always have to travel with me. It is  an EU passport, so we can access many countries without visa requirements.

But in case visa is required, do I need just 1 visa for all, or do I need a separate visa sheet for each.

Comment: I think this will depend primarily on which country you plan to visit. Could you please be more specific? Or are you looking for general examples of countries that go one way or another on this matter?

Comment: I would like to know whether or not I should register separate passports. I hoped that the answer is generic, one answer fits all countries with some tweaking between individual countries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visa requirements are country specific and some countries will require separate visas for dependents, most won't. Most commonly when dependents are involved they are added onto the main applicant's visa. On the visa application form you will be asked if there are any dependents on your passport and if the visa is granted it will include your dependents.